# C# Uri generator for resources

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to write a property, which will construct my resource URI.

I have my base class in `MyProject.Common` assembly which has implementation like

```
class abstract BaseItem
{
    public abstract string Path { get; }
    public Uri Path
    {
        return new Uri(string.Format("/{0};component{1}", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, Path ), UriKind.Relative);
    }
```

And my implementations are in different assemblies.

Problem: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName` return `MyProject.Common` assembly, not my implementation assembly

Question: How to archieve that?

Comment: I have also tried `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` and `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`. Entry returns my application assembly, Calling returns PresentationFramework assembly

Comment: Note also the proper syntax for [Resource File Pack URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly), and don't set `UriKind.Relative`.

Comment: If I put this Uri getter on proper assembly, it works perfectly (with Assembly name as string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you get the assembly from the actual derived type of BaseItem:

```
public abstract class BaseItem
{
    public abstract string Path { get; }

    public Uri Uri
    {
        get
        {
            return new Uri(string.Format("pack://application:,,,/{0};component/{1}",
                this.GetType().Assembly.FullName, Path));
        }
    }
}
```